# Blocking people nexus 5

Tags: call-screening

How do I block an unknown number on nexus 5 who keeps calling me . I have looked everywhere but I can't find the option

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an option that allows you to do it on stock android, you'd have to use an app. I've used [BlackList](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.baole.app.blacklist) before.

Comment: Suggestion for an app to use? This is a poor answer at the moment.

Comment: Well i have only used an app that does this once, it's called BlackList but i certainly won't recommend it without having used other apps of this kind

Comment: If you found the app useful then that's all you need to recommend it, even if there are better ones. Thanks for getting back as well, all too rare with most posters.

Comment: I'm just gonna link to it so op can check it out if he wants. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.baole.app.blacklist it worked when I used it, that's all i can recall (get it? )

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the [phone warrior app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.visinor.phonewarrior&hl=en). It helps to block unwanted calls and sms

Answer (score -1):

Use Truecaller app! You can even block a number from sending you texts!